# Using the Command Pattern in Android in combination with an Http Request Handler to handle its result

Tags: java, android, command-pattern

My actual question is down towards the bottom of the page, and may not require you to look at all of my code.

So I think I want to employ the Command Pattern in my Android application.  I have a class `HttpRequestHandler` which `extends AsyncTask` and thus has the `doInBackground` and `onPostExecute` methods.  `HttpRequestHandler` takes a URL, and an HttpRequest type as parameters.

What I want to do is pass a method (in the form of an interface) to the `HttpRequestHandler` so that in the `onPostExecute` I can invoke that method and have it display the result gotten from the Http request in the given textview.  This way I don't have to use a giant `switch(case)` in my `onPostExecute`

I need some help with the execution though.  In this case, I have two separate classes that implement Command.

```
public interface Command{
    public void execute(JSONObject json);
}

public class DisplayResult implements Command{

    public TextView textview;

    public DisplayResult(TextView textview){
        this.textview = textview;
    }
    @Override
    public void execute(JSONObject output){
        textview.setText(output.getString("mystring")
    }
}

public class ConfirmPost implements Command{

    public ConfirmPost(){
    }
    @Override
    public void execute(JSONObject output){
        Log.d("Success! ","POST successfull");
    }
}
```

And the two calls to `HTTPRequestHandler`, one passing a `DisplayResult` and one passing a `ConfirmPost` class.
    public static void

```
TextView mytextview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytextview);
new HttpRequestHandler(new DisplayResult(mytextview)).execute("myurl","GET");

new HttpRequestHandler(new ConfirmPost()).execute("myurl","POST");
```

Now it's in my `HttpRequestHandler` where I'm having the problem.

```
public class HttpRequestHandler extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
Command presenter;

    Public HttpRequestHandler(Object presenter){    
        this.presenter = (Command) presenter;
    }

    Public String doInBackground(String... uri){
       ...
    }

    Public onPostExecute(String result){
        presentation = new JSONObject(result);
        presenter.execute();
    }
```

Using Object as an argument type seems to me, simply by feeling, not to be best practice.  I've never seen anyone use it like this, and the idea of having to cast the given object as `Command` rubs me the wrong way.  Is there some way I can just make the class sort of *trust* that I'm giving it a Command object?

This is my first time using the Command Pattern, and I don't yet fully understand it.  Be gentle.

***UPDATE***

It looks like I want to be using Generics here.  I still don't really know how to execute that in a best practice manner though.  What I have now is:

```
Command presenter; 

public <Command> HttpRequestHandler(Command presenter){
    this.presenter = (com.example.myproject.Command) presenter;
    //ugly!
}
```

And this works just fine I can seemingly pass it any old implementation of `Command`, I just can't seem to find any references online which have the same syntax or functionality.  I've heard some mention of the factory pattern, but I have a feeling the Command Pattern doesn't rely on another pattern to be fully functional like this.  Any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: the "Be Gentle" part at the end shows how much a beginner on SO is afraid to ask question which might make sense and thats because of some hotheads who have earned good reputation but have no decency. It's a signal guys. "Be Gentle"

Comment: I've just asked so many seemingly innocuous questions about programming only to be heavily reprimanded for truly silly things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed it is a matter for Generics.  [Using Bounded Type Parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html) and by having `T` extend `Command`, I can ensure that my parameter will be a subclass (in this case implementation) of `Command`

The `HttpRequestHandler` should now look something like this

```
public class HttpRequestHandler extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    Command presenter;

    public <T extends Command> HttpRequestHandler(T presenter){
        this.presenter =  presenter;
    }

    presenter.execute("Success!");
}
```

No horrendous casting necessary.